# Error Packaging an adobe AIR application to .air using the ADT compiler

Tags: adobe, air

I get the following error

> 302: Root content index.html file missing from package

```
adt -package -storetype pkcs12 -keystore Mycert.pfx Display/build/display.air Display/source/application.xml Display/source/index.html Display/source/icons Display/source/js Display/source/sounds
```

my application.xml is fine

```
 <initialWindow>
    <content>index.html</content>
    <visible>true</visible>
    <width>160</width>
    <height>120</height>
  </initialWindow>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

302: Root content file missing from package - The SWF or HTML file referenced in the  element of the application descriptor must be added to the package by including it in the files listed on the ADT command line.

Also make sure spelling is correct in your application.xml

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late for this, but one never know who care, and I recently has the same issue, and at last, I figure it out that in the command line, my last parameter, who get the SWF file, has a folder, so, remove it and I just left the SWF name, and thereafter everything it's ok.

My complete command was:

```
adt -package -target ipa-debug -keystore path/to/key.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass YourSecretPass -provisioning-profile path/to/file.mobileprovision myInstaller.ipa src/MyProject-app.xml MyProject.swf
```

...and course, the .SWF file must be in the project root, same place where I write de adt command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem right now. I found this thread on Adobe's help forum that discusses this issue:
http://forums.adobe.com/thread/91611

Basically it's saying to put -C before the filenames in the adt command because

> when you use -C, it will put everything in the specified directory into the root of the application folder